# What is the idiomatic way of returning optional values?

Tags: ruby, crystal-lang

I just kinda ran against a wall here.
Let's say my code is something like the following:

```
def foo
    if bar
        123
    else
        nil
    end
end
```

Here the return value is either Int or Nil.
I'm used to the concept of optionals (in languages like Rust, F#, Haskell) and this is really confusing me.

I realize that I can return a value of any type without problems, but coming from a more functional background it just feels wrong.

In Rust, I'd return an `Option<T>`. That way I could easily test whether `Some` value was returned, or no value (`None`). In Ruby/Crystal that seems like a silly thing to do though.

So, here's the question:
Should I just return `nil` in the case that there is no useful value to return and test against that, and is this the idiomatic way of handling such cases? If not, how should I do it in an idiomatic way?

Comment: To the close-voter, could you please explain yourself, so I can improve my question?

Comment: I don't think mixing Ruby and Crystal in this question is reasonable - not every Ruby idiom is a Crystal idiom.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia that is right. I tagged both because in this context it didn't matter too much. Crystal has `Nil` type and tries to feel like Ruby, so I think this question applies to both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, return `nil`

Returning `nil` is the encouraged best practice in Ruby. You can check for that with `foo.nil?`

NB, if you are interested in learning more best practices for Ruby, best refer to the book "Ruby Best Practices" by Gregory Brown.

---

On a related note, the language defaults to returning `nil` in many places. For example, when an `if` expression has no else block it's return value for the else block is `nil`.

So you can simplify your example as

```
def foo
  123 if bar
end
```

which will return `nil` if `bar` is not truthy

Comment: Thank you. Could you expand your answer a little and maybe add a link to official Ruby documentation that encourages that behavior? Other than that, the answer is good, I'll accept it in a few minutes :)

Comment: @splittydev anything in particular that you would like me to expand on? Official ruby documentation does not cover best practices like this, it is assumed that you learn them from other sources. The best reference is probably the book "Ruby Best Practices" by Gregory Brown

Comment: if the official ruby documentation doesn't cover this, then your answer is perfectly fine. thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Crystal `nil` is the preferred way to indicate the absence of a value, and is usually combined with other values to mean "something can either be returned (`T`) or not (`Nil`)". The API docs also explain this and mention several ways to deal with nil: https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.1/Nil.html